# Is there some way of put count in "with" clause of Query builder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, query-builder, knex.js, adonis.js

I made a clone of twitter in AdonisJS and i get “tweets” of this way:

```
const tweets = await Post.query()
  .whereIn('user_id', followersIds)
  .with('user')
  .with('favorites')
  .with('replies')
  .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
  .paginate(params.page, 3)
```

The problem is that in this method I get tweet whit all replies tables and I only need the tweet whit count or `replies.lenght`.

I thought of use a buckle for this but possibly exist another way 4 make this in query builder…

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.withCount()`

try:

```
const tweets = await Post.query()
  .whereIn('user_id', followersIds)
  .with('user')
  .with('favorites')
  .withCount('replies')
  .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
  .paginate(params.page, 3)
```

you should see a property named replies_count

https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_counts